# Хочу поучаствовать в проекте

Tags: php, проект

Где найти такие проекты, что бы можно было поучаствовать в них как программист. Я только немного знаю php и MySQL(работаю в Linux Ubuntu 10.10). Кто может взяться за меня и дать возможность получить бесценный опыт? Возможно, если проект будет интересным, готов там остаться на постоянке.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает начать свой проект? Придумайте идею и стремитесь ее реализовать попутно много чему научитесь.

Comment: это интересно, но долго. нужна компания для обмена идеями и реализациями. я конечно иногда жлоб, но и люблю помочь и отдать что-то свое. проект свой есть, но что-бы его реализовать нужны знания.
знания лучше познаются на чужих примерах.

Comment: чаще всего начать свой проект мешает лень, да и первые проблемы убивают все желание продолжать дальше =(

Answer (score 0):

В Open Source тебе дорога. Ищи проект, который по душе или действительно сделай что-нибудь сам полезное для общества, критики получишь море как конструктивной так и не очень.

Comment: я знаю что open-source, но нигде не видел сервисов где люди предлагают присоединится к проектам или сообщают что уже существует такой проект. идти к иностранным коллегам - не вижу смысла, у них другой тип общения, или я не пойму их или меня.

Answer (score 0):

я бы взял, но мне надо со знаниям асп.нэт, лучше со знаниями верстки, ява-скрипта, цсс, хтмл...